# How to bulkify a trigger with many dependent SOQL queries

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

In our org when we clone a case we would like to bring with it only the most 20 recent email messages and attachments. This is to avoid encountering heap size limits.

The below is the code that currently performs this functionality however it is located in a trigger and I need to refactor it to remove the queries that are in the `for` loops. The problem is the queries are dependent on each other:

```
for(Case c : newCaseMap.values()){
    if(c.isclone()){
        Id clonedfrom = c.getCloneSourceId();
        Case oldCase = [Select id, Thread_ID__c, CaseNumber from Case where id =: clonedFrom];
        List<EmailMessage> emList = new List<EmailMessage>();
        List<Attachment> attachList = new List<Attachment>();
        List<EmailMessage> emList2 = new List<EmailMessage>();
        List<Attachment> attachList2 = new List<Attachment>();

        emList = [SELECT id, ParentId, FROMAddress, HasAttachment, CcAddress, BccAddress, ToAddress, messageDate, Subject, textBody, htmlBody, Incoming, is_OOO_Reply__c FROM emailmessage WHERE ParentId =: clonedFROM ORDER BY messageDate DESC LIMIT 50];
        
        filesList = [SELECT id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: clonedFROM OR LinkedEntityId IN: emList];

        integer i = 0;
        for(emailmessage e : emList){
            if(i<20){
                //manually recreate the email message and assign it to the newly cloned case                    
                emList2.add(newEmail);
                i++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }                     

        for(List<attachment> al : [SELECT id, ParentId, name, body, ContentType FROM attachment WHERE (ParentId =: clonedFROM OR parentId IN: emList) AND (NOT ContentType LIKE 'image%')]){
            for(attachment a : al){
                //manually recreate the attachment and assign it to the newly cloned case
                attachList2.add(newAttach);
            }
        }

        if(emList2.size() > 0){
            insert emList2;
        }
        if(attachList2.size() > 0){
            insert attachList2;
        }
    }
}
```

I know this code can be improved elsewhere and I will be doing that however what I am struggling with is how to remove the SOQL queries from the `for` loop while still being able to specify only the 20 most recent emails are cloned.

I have tried using maps etc but I cannot visualise the data structures properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your queries are all for objects related to a case, you should be able to make use of parent-child subqueries.

Something like `[SELECT Id, Thread_Id__c, CaseNumber, (SELECT Id FROM EmailMessages LIMIT 20), (SELECT Id FROM Attachments), (SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds]`

The advantages of that, besides being able to remove the query from the loop are:

- You're reducing the number of queries you're using
- The child records are associated to the parent record (you don't have to group them yourself, and they're available when you iterate over the parent records)
- Some things that you have in Apex right now, like limiting to 20 email messages per case, can be done in SOQL instead

That's not the only way you could do it. Along the lines of what you mentioned, you could gather the parent ids, perform the individual queries, and then build maps (like `Map<Id of Account, List<Child SObject>>`), but why make your life harder than it needs to be?

+edit:

The one thing I did miss is that your query for `ContentDocumentLink` also involves records where the parent is an email message. For that, I don't think there's a good way around needing to have a separate query and build a map.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic appears incomplete, but this really is just a matter of using Map objects. Here's my translation of what you have so far:

```
Map<Id, Case> oldCases = new Map<Id, Case>();
Map<Id, EmailMessage[]> messages = new Map<Id, EmailMessage[]>();
Map<Id, ContentDocumentLink[]> attachments = new Map<Id, ContentDocumentLink[]>();

for(Case record: newCaseMap.values()) {
    if(record.isClone()) {
        // For each clone, initialize various maps
        Id cloneSourceId = record.getCloneSourceId();
        oldCases.put(cloneSourceId, null);
        messages.put(cloneSourceId, new EmailMessage[0]);
        attachments.put(cloneSourceId, new ContentDocumentLink[0]);
    }
}
// Nothing to do here
if(oldCases.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
// Get clone source records
oldCases.putAll([SELECT Thread_ID__c, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id = :oldCases.keySet()]);
for(EmailMessage message: [
        SELECT  ParentId, FROMAddress, HasAttachment, CcAddress, BccAddress, ToAddress, messageDate, 
                Subject, textBody, htmlBody, Incoming, is_OOO_Reply__c 
        FROM emailmessage 
        WHERE ParentId = :oldCases.keySet() 
        ORDER BY messageDate DESC]) {
    EmailMessage[] emailList = messages.get(message.ParentId);
    // Get 50 most recent emails for each case.
    if(emailList.size() < 50) {
        emailList.add(message);
        // And initialize content document link lists
        attachments.put(message.Id, new ContentDocumentLink[0]);
    }
}
for(ContentDocumentLink link: [
        SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ShareType 
        FROM ContentDocumentLink 
        WHERE LinkedEntityId = :oldCases.keySet() OR LinkedEntityId = :attachments.keySet()]) {
    // Sort CDL into appropriate buckets
    attachments.get(link.LinkedEntityId).add(link);
}
```

You will need a few more Map objects to link the old records to the new ones, but it should be pretty straight forward from this point.

P.S. You don't need to check if a list is empty before using DML on it. That was an old technique to reduce governor limits, but Apex no longer counts empty DML operations against governor limits.